# What causes the discrepancy in outcomes between these Golang code snippets?

Tags: go

Does anyone know why I'm getting different results for the following two Golang code snippets below?
In both applications, the String() method constructs a slice of strings representing the individual bytes in the IPAddr and then uses strings.Join to concatenate them into a dotted-quad IP address format. However, the two applications produce different results for the same input.
Notice the difference in how the two applications construct the slice of strings to be joined in the String() method in the for loop.

Application 1

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

type IPAddr [4]byte

func (ip IPAddr) String() string {
    s := make([]string, len(ip))
    for i := range ip {
        s[i] = strconv.Itoa(int(ip[i]))
    }
    return strings.Join(s, ".")
}

func main() {
    hosts := map[string]IPAddr{
        "loopback":  {127, 0, 0, 1},
        "googleDNS": {8, 8, 8, 8},
    }
    for name, ip := range hosts {
        fmt.Printf("%v: %v\n", name, ip.String())
    }
}

// Result:
// loopback: 127.0.0.1
// googleDNS: 8.8.8.8
```

Application 2:

```
// Application 2

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

type IPAddr [4]byte

func (ip IPAddr) String() string {
    s := make([]string, len(ip))
    for _, val := range ip {
        s = append(s, strconv.Itoa(int(val)))
    }
    return strings.Join(s, ".")
}

func main() {
    hosts := map[string]IPAddr{
        "loopback":  {127, 0, 0, 1},
        "googleDNS": {8, 8, 8, 8},
    }
    for name, ip := range hosts {
        fmt.Printf("%v: %v\n", name, ip.String())
    }
}

// Result:
// loopback: ....127.0.0.1
// googleDNS: ....8.8.8.8
```

Answer (score 3):

In your second `String` method...

```
func (ip IPAddr) String() string {
    s := make([]string, len(ip))
    for _, val := range ip {
        s = append(s, strconv.Itoa(int(val)))
    }
    return strings.Join(s, ".")
}
```

...you're starting with a slice of 4 strings. That is, before the loop, `s` is `{"", "", "", ""}`. For each iteration of the loop, you're appending a new item to the slice. If we add a `fmt.Printf` statement inside the loop, like this:

```
    for _, val := range ip {
        s = append(s, strconv.Itoa(int(val)))
        fmt.Printf("s: %#v\n", s)
    }
```

We see as output:

```
s: []string{"", "", "", "", "127"}
s: []string{"", "", "", "", "127", "0"}
s: []string{"", "", "", "", "127", "0", "0"}
s: []string{"", "", "", "", "127", "0", "0", "1"}
```

When you join that slice of strings on `.`, you're joining 8 items. The first four are empty which is why you're results start with `....`.

You'll get the results you expect if you start with an empty slice:

```
func (ip IPAddr) String() string {
    s := []string{}
    for _, val := range ip {
        s = append(s, strconv.Itoa(int(val)))
    }
    return strings.Join(s, ".")
}
```

Comment: "You'll get the results you expect if you start with an empty slice" It's better to initialize the slice with 0 length and the anticipated capacity since you know exactly what it's going to need.   Personally, I rather prefer the indexing `s[i] = ...`

Answer (score 2):

this first snippet creates `s` and then fills each of its elements with a string representation of the integer value of the byte.

```
    s := make([]string, len(ip))
    for _, val := range ip {
        s = append(s, strconv.Itoa(int(val)))
    }
```

This second snippet creates `s` with `len(ip)` also, but instead of setting one of `s[:len(ip)]`, it *appends* to those original `len(ip)`, resulting in `s` being `2xlen(ip)` elements long, with the first half of them unset.  The zero value of a string is `""`, so there are additional dots at the beginning.

```
    s := make([]string, len(ip))
    for _, val := range ip {
        s = append(s, strconv.Itoa(int(val)))
    }
```

[The alternative to method one using `append` is to set the *capacity*, not the *length*, in `make`.](https://go.dev/play/p/rTdE3Vo9QnB)

```
    s := make([]string,0, len(ip))
    for _, val := range ip {
        s = append(s, strconv.Itoa(int(val)))
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the second approach

```golang
func (ip IPAddr) String() string {
    s := make([]string, len(ip))
    for _, val := range ip {
        s = append(s, strconv.Itoa(int(val)))
    }
    return strings.Join(s, ".")
}
```

you're first `making` an array of length `len(ip)`, and then appending items at the end of it. So it ends up with length `2*len(ip)`.